# Can someone tell me if my answer to this Past Paper Question is correct please?

Tags: c++, qt, design-patterns

I am working through a past paper as practice and came across the following question:

Consider the `ActorList` class below

```cpp
class ActorList
{
public:
  ~ActorList();
  static ActorList* getActorList();
  bool addActor(Actor *a);
  int size() const;
  Actor* getActor(int i);
private:
   ActorList();
   static ActorList* actorList;
   QList<Actor*> list;
}
```

No other information is given.

Am I correct in saying that the design pattern used here is the Singleton design pattern?

Comment: Judging by private constructor and static factory method, probably yes. Doesn't follow the rule of 3/5/0 though.

Comment: "Past paper"...

Comment: It's a broken singleton, allowing `auto copy = *ActorList::get_instance();`.  Also missing a `;` at the end.